# append lt IE using document.createElement

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my code:

```
function addTag(name, attributes, sync, cond) {
var el = document.createElement(name),
    attrName;

for (attrName in attributes) {
  el.setAttribute(attrName, attributes[attrName]);
}

sync ? document.write(outerHTML(el)) : headEl.appendChild(el);
```

}

```
 function outerHTML(node){
// if IE, Chrome take the internal method otherwise build one
return node.outerHTML || (
    function(n){
        var div = document.createElement('div'), h;
        div.appendChild(n);
        h = div.innerHTML;
        div = null;
        return h;
    })(node);
```

}

Here is my call:

```
addTag('script',{"src":"\/\/oss.maxcdn.com\/html5shiv\/3.7.2\/html5shiv.min.js"},1,'lt IE 9');
```

How do I place `less than` tags in my code? The argument is `cond`

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
function addTag(name, attributes, sync, cond) {
    var el = document.createElement(name),
        attrName,
        condElement
    ;

    for (attrName in attributes) {
        el.setAttribute(attrName, attributes[attrName]);
    }

    switch (cond) {
        case 'lt IE 9':
            el = document.createComment(
                '[if lt IE 9]>' + outerHTML(el) + '<![endif]'
            );

            break;
    }

    sync ? document.write(outerHTML(el)) : headEl.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: how do i implement this in my function?

Comment: dont you need to place the element content inside the comment element

Comment: You're 100% right.. Try the updated code but not sure if the html tags won't be escaped.